# Extracting json data using variable variables?

Tags: php, arrays, json, variable-variables

I have a .json file with some data I'm trying to extract. What I need to know is how I would go about making the below variable dynamic.

```
$MapData['MapData']['0,0']['type'];
```

What I need to know is how I would replace the 0,0 with $x,$y variables. I've tried to use variable as a variable name.

```
$MapString = "MapData['MapData']['".$x.",".$y."']['type']";
$MapStringData = $$MapString;
```

I was unsuccessful in getting this to work. Is there something I'm missing or not doing right?

Comment: Variable variables is unclear and this question is also unclear. Maybe you could include input and expected output

Comment: when using a foreach instead of a for you wouldn't have that problem at all!

Comment: I've updated my question to be a little more simple to understand, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the last cell having the highest row/column number as the key, then you first can extract the keys for the MapData, and with the last (using`end`) element split it using `explode()` with a `,`.  This uses `list()` to assign the two values to the rows and column fields...

```
$cells = array_keys($MapData['MapData']);
list($MapRows, $MapCols) = explode(",", end($cells));
```